# href's for a github pages project

Tags: github-pages, sveltekit

I have a github pages svelte app based on myuser.github.io - it works.

I have also created a github pages based on a project (sveltekit) so the url is myuser.github.io/sveltekit. The repo is set so that github pages is served from gh-pages and root. This only sorts of works(!)

The problem is navigation. Here is the navigation code in __layout.svelte

```
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/settings">Settings</a>
</nav>
```

But when I run this under github Pages, the home page comes up but the other links show as myuser/github.io/about which will give a 404.

if the code is

```
<nav>
    <a href="./">Home</a>
    <a href="./about">About</a>
    <a href="./settings">Settings</a>
</nav>
```

then other links work once and are then eg myuser.github.io/about/settings which is, once again, a 404.

So though github pages allows me to have sub repos under the top level, navigation for these is based on root of the top level rather than root being defined as the root of that repo. And the only options are root and /docs.

Is there a way of setting root to /sveltekit/ ?

Another problem is that styling is displaying on github pages though does when the site is run under preview or dev.

Comment: I am wondering if this is how it is supposed to work. That the different repos make a hierarchy of the website.

Answer (score 1):

I made two changes

svelte.config.js in kit

```
        paths: {
            base: '/sveltekit',
            assets: '/sveltekit'
        },
```

and in __layout.svelte

```
<script>
  import { base } from '$app/paths';
</script>

<nav>
    <a href="{base}/">Home</a>
    <a href="{base}/about">About</a>
    <a href="{base}/settings">Settings</a>
</nav>
```

And now navigation works and I also get styling.